# How to use Dotfuscator

Tags: asp.net, obfuscation, dotfuscator

Currently I'm developing a ASP.NET mvc2 project. In that i have some dll files. I want to protect it using a obfuscator. Can any one give me some help in order to do this using Dotfuscator.Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may see this article : [Protecting your .NET applications](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=507)

> This article demonstrates how to use Dotfuscator which is shipped
>   freely with Visual Studio 2010 to protect .NET assemblies and making
>   the process of reverse engineering difficult.

But remember you can't 100% secure your code from de-compiling, you can only make it difficult to de-compile.

Comment: Thank you Habib. Could you please explain how can i automate this process when build my project.